# Forcing content to not overflow to the right of the screen

Tags: css

I'm trying to make all content of all websites in my browser to squeeze to screen width by userstylesheets. I'm stuck at making this work:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/psol

[The content doesn't use my browser's horizontal scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOch4.png) making `width:100%` selector useless. Any other options?

BTW in `width:100%` I'm assuming it's 100% of it's parent's width. How can I get 100% of screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try getting rid of this

```
#gc-main {
  overflow: auto;
}
```